# What does "distilled" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

As in "He is the most distilled form of the Sherlock Holmes character I've seen."

Does "distilled form" here mean something that expresses the essence of the character (Holmes)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is right.  Distilling (in the literally sense) is a method of purifying a spirit, or separating different volatile chemicals.

A highly distilled vodka is one which is mostly pure alcohol

So by analogy a highly distilled form of the character shows the pure characteristics or "expresses the essence of the character".